# Партционирование

Tags: mysql

Есть сервер zabbix с БД mariadb, там настроено партиционирование скриптом, возникла необходимость перейти на более свежую версию БД и новый zabbix, установил Mysql Ver 8.0.29, залил дамп БД, запустил скрипт, он пишет, что все разделы партиционированы, но сервер в логах пишет ошибки вида

```
[Z3005] query failed: [1526] Table has no partition for value 1657090293 
[insert into history_uint (itemid,clock,ns,value) values (79759,1657090293,586655200,593701);
```

Как это можно побороть?

Comment: *там настроено партиционирование скриптом* Это, блин, как? *запустил скрипт, он пишет, что все разделы партиционированы* Покажите полный SHOW CREATE TABLE для таблицы.

Comment: https://cloud.mail.ru/public/WBku/y2Mericvj  
вот вывод

Comment: Ну что я могу сказать... скрипт - говно. Для указанного значения действительно нет партиции. При правильном партиционировании в списке партиций ВСЕГДА есть раздел `VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)`, в который и валится всё, что не соответствует другим партициям.

Comment: А создать ее руками можно?

Comment: Конечно, можно. `ALTER TABLE history_uint ADD PARTITION p_maxvalue (VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)) ENGINE = InnoDB;`

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE)) ENGINE = InnoDB' at line 1

Comment: Ну кагбэ мог и сам поправить.. `ALTER TABLE history_uint 
ADD PARTITION (PARTITION p_maxvalue VALUES LESS THAN (MAXVALUE));`. [ALTER TABLE Partition Operations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/), [Partitioning](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/partitioning.html).